# Cypress opening and closing after updating to the cypress10

Tags: cypress

I have installed cypress10 in my project which was perfectly running on cypress9.7. After the update when I hit the command cypress opened and closed. Can someone help me to fix this issue?

No errors generated in the console.
[image]

Comment: Try "npm test --verbose" it should print out the logs which might give you more insight into why cypress isn't opening

Comment: What is in the script for `test`?

Comment: test is my project name

Comment: @TheFlorinator This is i got for npm test --verbose command. 

> cypress open

[..................] / : timing npm:load Completed in 51ms
npm timing command:run-script Completed in 4381ms
npm timing command:test Completed in 4390ms
npm verb exit 2147483651
npm timing npm Completed in 4451ms
npm verb code 2147483651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found a solution just run the VS code as an admin user this issue will not come up again.